# UV Map editing with python

Tags: python, add-on, development

I have been trying to figure out the best way to make a material for Minecraft blocks inside of my addon. Excluding special cases, a Minecraft block is a 1-meter cube that has an image texture of 16x16 pixels for each side. This is stored in a png file in the game files to which I have access. The goal of my script is to add a cube, properly align the UVs, and add a material with an image texture. I have no problem doing this in regular Blender. Add a cube, tab into edit mode, select all the vertices, open a UV editing window, select the whole UV map, rotate -90°, scale up by 4, and shift to the right by .5. This scales and aligns the UV map so that when I assign the material and set the image interpolation to 'closest' it properly displayed the block.

The issue I am running into is the complexity of manipulating UV maps via python code. It requires loads of matrix multiplication which I only half understand. So far I have managed to rotate -90° and scale up by 4. What I can't figure out how to do is shift it right by 0.5

My questions:

1. Is there an easier/faster way to assign a 16x16 pixel image as a texture for each side of a 1-meter cube? If so, what is the workflow in Blender and/or BPY?
2. Is there some function or library that helps with editing UV maps in python?
3. If there isn't a better way, how would I go about shifting the UV map to the right by 0.5?

EDIT: I figured out how to shift the UVs. But I would still like to know if there is a better way. Especially for the blocks that aren't 1-meter cube.